# How can I pass ItemTemplate value to another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Greetings fellow developers. I am new to ASP.NET C# so pardon me if there are areas that I missed out/

Current in my project, I have this Gridview - where I used "TemplateField" for almost every data field. My issue is, I do not know how can I pass the  value in  to another page. I tried using SESSION but unfortunately, it is not working. I also tried using BOUNDFIELD, it works but it does not fulfil my project requirement as the default setting for BOUNDFIELD is textbox, I want it to be a DROPDOWN LIST control instead. Any kind advice would be much appreciated. Attached below is my codes.

WebForm1.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="Gridview1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="Gridview1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="Gridview1_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="Gridview1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="Gridview1_RowUpdating" ShowFooter="True" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-responsive table-bordered" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="CID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Transaction ID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbleditid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden-xs" />
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden-xs" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CCID">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblccid2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblccid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CCID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <%--<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox_Cat" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Category") %>'></asp:TextBox>--%>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="--Select--">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Transportation">Transportation</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Children">Children </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Food">Food</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory1" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Transportation</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Children </asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Food </asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Category") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Edited">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last_Edited") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTime" runat="server" ToolTip="DD/MM/YYYY"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Last_Edited") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add New"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnClick="PassData">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
   protected void PassData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        GridViewRow gr = ((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
        Session["Category"] = gr.Cells[1].Text.Trim();

        Response.Redirect("AfterUserMthlyExpenses.aspx");


        }
```

WebForm2.aspx

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblPassCategory" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

WebForm2.aspx.cs

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Passing "Category" from previous page
                lblPassCategory.Text = Session["Category"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, really one should hold off on the passing of the value to the next page until such time you have a working simple answer to select/get the given row that you clicked on right?

Be it a repeater, grid view, list view (details view) etc.?

In asp.net they ALL FOLLOW the same process. You want to have that button click set/move/change to the correct given row that you clicked on. Until you have that “movement” or selection of the row occur, then you will fail at attempting to grab values from that row.

So, looking at this, you have a link button (it could be a asp.net button if want – don’t matter), you need that button to trigger/set/move/cause the row you are working on to change FIRST and BEFORE you attempt to grab data/values from that given row.

The WAY you do this is to add a special command. As noted, this works for list view/grivdview/repeater and MANY more data bound controls.

so what you learn here can apply to just about ANY data aware control (that repeats data).

So, add this to the one link button in the item template:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server"
       CommandName = "MyJump"
       CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Category") %>'
       >Select</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So, the INSTANT you add CommandName="Select", then this will cause TWO events of the grid to fire.

OnRowComand:

The row command event will fire. But the row HAS NOT YET changed!

However, since we use CommandArgument and pass "Catagory", then we of course can use the rowcomamnd event, and pick up the CommandArgument value.

So, you can have this code in row command event:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand


    Debug.Print("row command = " & e.CommandName)
    Debug.Print("row arg = " & e.CommandArgument)

    If e.CommandName = "MySelect" Then

        ' do whatever

    End If

End Sub
```

Note how we don't need (you can remove) the on-click event for that button - you use the rowcommand event stub, and pick up the custom command name you passed (MySelect).

You can ALSO trigger the selected row event to fire. This would allow you to use/keep/have your EXISTING code click stub for your button.

However you now MUST change the CommandName from "your custom" name to either;

```
Select (move the grid pointer)
Edit   - trigger edit event
Delete  - trigger delete event
```

However, in your button click (as you have now).

You could try this:

```
    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = btn.Parent.Parent

    Debug.Print("btn row sel = " & gvRow.RowIndex)

    Debug.Print("btn argument = " & btn.CommandArgument)
```

So you can try btn.Parent (that will be the grid cell, and parent again will return the ONE row as you have. From that, you can grab any value out of that row.

eg:

```
 dim myLable as label
 myLabel = gvRow.FindControl("Label1")
 debug.print myLabel.Text (should return catagory).
```

Probably most easy to just add a CommandArgument, and pick it up from sender.

Now that you first and foremost verify that you have the correct value, then you can shove that value into session. in fact you can even shove in the whole gvRow into session, and thus pass all of the values of that row to the page you jump to.